# Publish Android App to a limited group of users

Tags: android, publish, group

I would like to publish an Android app via the Google PlayStore and this app should however only be made available to a restricted group of users.
I would like to distribute the app if possible not manually as .apk file.
In my research, I have also repeatedly come across such recommendations that you can publish the app as a beta. However, I would like to avoid that as well.
For alternatives it is also important that the distribution is as simple as in the Play Store.
I'm also aware that the question has already been asked here with a few minor variations, so it would be a possible duplicate, but I couldn't really find an acceptable solution among the other entries yet.

Is this possible?
Or rather, via which way can this be achieved? Directly via settings in the Google Play Console?
Or is there another way?

Can someone maybe help me with this?

Many greetings

Comment: Unfortunately (as far as I am aware) this perfectly fits for beta-testing with an invite, so there might not be any other way

Answer (score 0):

To publish an app only to a few users, you can use the "Publish Private Apps" from the Google admin console, and for more information, please refer to this link - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9874937?hl=en.

Hope this helped...